# Activiti Tomcat configuration

Tags: java, tomcat8, activiti, bpmn, lib

to deploy my project activi, I copied .jar file to webapps\activiti-explorer\WEB-INF\lib. But when I restart Tomcat, activiti-explorer resets, so all my users and groups are removed. And every time I stop tomcat and restart it I have to redo everything again.

So, what should I do ?

Many thanks

Comment: Even I'm facing the same problem, every time I restart tomcat server, even all the workflow I had created are deleted from the activiti explorer. Can anyone reply on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "DatabaseSchemaUpdate" is set to "create-drop", this means all the tables will be dropped and created fresh every time an engine is created. Change this to "true" in your properties file. Example in `3. Configuration - 3.1. Creating a ProcessEngine` in the [userguide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#configuration) will help you configuring your process engine properly. find the activiti.cfg.xml file in your classpath.